# Assign intermediary results inside a function if it is thereafter used at least twice?

Tags: r

If I have a function that modifies it's input and then does two different things with the modified object, should I always assign the intermediary result?

Just an example using gsub on a vector and saving two different files,
modify_character_vector seems to be faster, can this result be generalized?

My impression of functional programming was that modify_character_vector2 was the cleaner approach.

```
library(rbenchmark)
modify_character_vector <- function(v) {
    b <- gsub("a", "b", v)
    saveRDS(b, "~/filename.rds")
    saveRDS(b, "~/filename1.rds")
}

modify_character_vector2 <- function(v) {
    saveRDS(gsub("a", "b", v), "~/filename2.rds")
    saveRDS(gsub("a", "b", v), "~/filename3.rds")
}

benchmark(
    "assignment" = {
        v <- rep(letters, 1000)
        modify_character_vector(v)
    },
    "no_assignment" = {
        v <- rep(letters, 1000)
        modify_character_vector2(v)
    },
    replications = 1000
)
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I prefer the first function (saving intermediate to `b`), for two reasons: (1) it might be "expensive" to generate that intermediate object, in which case doing it twice is just unnecessary; or even if that is not the case, (2) if I need to troubleshoot a problem and only fix *one* of the otherwise-identical `gsub` calls, then I have inconsistent behavior. (And I do not agree that `_vector2` is the cleaner approach, though that just an opinion.)

Comment: I do not believe in its pragmatic form that *functional programming* dissuades the use of storing intermediate objects in this fashion. Others may disagree.

Comment: Thanks, I was mostly wondering if R remembers the function call gsub("a", "b", v) and it's output, so that it can make use of the output again. And forcing memoization in every case is a bit overkill.

Comment: R does not auto-memoize ... think about non-deterministic functions (randomness or pulls from an external data source) and the impact that would have. There's always [`memoize`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memoise/index.html), though that might be *more* overkill :-)